# definition of personal data collection related to privacy policy

Tags: privacy, data-ownership, data-protection, social-media

So I am about to publish a mobile app and I need a privacy policy, although my app doesn't really **collect** any type of user information, is there some kind of definition about what it means to "collect" in these cases?

Is it considered collecting if I log the user onto her social media and show her some social media api informations and I only save locally (inside her mobile) her social media authentication cookie?
My app (and I) would have practically no knowledge of anybody's personal data as soon as I don't send anything outside the device (to a remote database or else)

Comment: What jurisdiction? The UK's Information Commissioner's Office has a great website with many explanations and examples. https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/.

Answer (score 1):

Her social media authentication **is** personal data.

Comment: uhmm does not look any personal: it is just a meaningless one time token that is useless without her username and password (which does not get collected by apps, only apple / google / facebook / twitter has those)

Comment: @Edoardo for the period of its validity, it's not meaningless at all - and if it's a JWT, then it could contain plenty of personally identifiable information available to anyone who wants to read it (most JWT tokens are signed but not encrypted - their payload may contain email addresses, usernames, real names and other information related to the account holder).

Comment: @Moo please look here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/oauth oauth tokens afaik are not JWT, they do not carry any type of user information, they are part of the authentication flow to make sure that the the guy who initiated the whole process has access to the data

Comment: @Edoardo sorry, but you aren't exactly correct - https://oauth.net/2/jwt/ - I'm a software developer and I work with oauth and JWT all the time.

Comment: @Moo uh! I stand corrected then, although from your oauth link it says that "JWTs can be used as OAuth 2.0 Bearer Tokens..." that does not mean that they are using it, moreover, in twitter case at least, oauth2 with the bearer token is used only for Application-only authentication which gives you access to public data only.

Comment: @Edoardo as I said in my original comment, "and _*if*_ it's a JWT, then it _*could*_ contain..." - you never said which social media service, and in any case the token they use now might not be the token they use tomorrow.  I was pointing out that just because all you get is the token, that doesn't mean you can rely on the fact that you haven't been given any personal data - there could be personal data in the token which is accessible to you, and you need to be both aware of that possibility and be prepared to manage it.

Comment: @Moo twitter is the use case, sorry, I didn't specify it; from the page I mentioned before you will understand that they use oauth 2.0 only for app only authentication which will give your app access only to public data, even if they include data inside the JWT that data is public so not pertinent to this post. As far as the user authentication goes, they use OAuth 1a (access token for user context), I am not aware of anyway one can include a JWT in a so called 3 legged oauth, are you? I am including their doc https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth

Comment: @Moo ...and the specification https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/